# Fast PDF reader that remembers the last viewed page

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

I have tried a few pdf readers : Adobe , foxit , and evince .

However, all of them have one basic flaw/ short coming compared to their windows and android counterparts. I have pdf files with many pages( thousands per file), which cannot be read in one go. So I would prefer the reader to restore to that last page where I left. Adding custom bookmarks is not a solution since there will be too many of them, and they'll be useless every time.

However, every time, I restart my system and open the pdf files, they open from page 1 and not that last page. This is very inconvenient as a lot of time gets spoiled just to recall where I left, and then find that page. This is unlike in windows and android, where the reader remembers where I left.

So is there any option in the readers which I am missing, or can you please suggest some other reader ( possibly light weight and fast, like foxit ; evince is very slow for me) which includes this functionality, as I am unable to find any.

Thank you

Edit:

I tried xpdf as mentioned in comments , re-installed adobe and evince just to make sure they work like I expect, but they dont. Evince does remember past history, but it is very slow and takes time to load even the next page. xpdf doesnt remember, neither does adobe or foxit.

( However, I seem to have run into a new issue as well. The newly installed programs dont show up in the list when I decided to change application defaults. Adobe was already installed earlier and showed in list as well. After reinstallation, its there, but doesnt show up in list, although I managed to change defaults using ubuntu tweak. )

Comment: Try using the 'bookmark' feature that comes standard with Document Viewer in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I use default pdf reader(evince) it will restores to last viewed page (where i left) everytime. Can't say what settings problem your facing, but those pdf readers you mentioned have this feature. Not a flaw in them.

Comment: @Sudheer . Evince is darn slow for big pdf files . And in fact, yes these readers do restore to where I left, but only so long as my system is on ( that too sometimes). That is, I opened a file in reader and then closed the reader. After reopening the reader, it will restore. But if I shut down my system, it wont restore the last page next time. This is the main problem.

Comment: have you tried `xpdf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KDE's Okular viewer does remember the last reading position, but it is not necessarily lightweight, especially if you don't use KDE software at the moment and need all the dependencies just for this one tool.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying out [MuPDF](http://mupdf.com/):

> a lightweight PDF and XPS viewer
>
> The renderer in MuPDF is tailored for high quality anti-aliased graphics. It renders text with metrics and spacing accurate to within fractions of a pixel for the highest fidelity in reproducing the look of a printed page on screen.
>
> MuPDF is also small, fast, and yet complete.

In my experience it is lightning fast.

Comment: Although okular did the job, i'll give it a try as well. Thanks.

Comment: Does mupdf really remember the last viewed page? Doesn't look so to me, on Ubuntu 16.04 (1.7a-1)